# Settings http headers in Java 6 SE httpserver

Tags: java, rss, http-headers, httpserver

I try to publish Atom feed (generated with Rome) using Java 6 SE httpserver. For correct feed discovery in FireFox I need custom headers.

This is my code:

```
 Headers headers=e.getRequestHeaders();
 ArrayList<String>list=new ArrayList<String>();
 list.add("application/atom+xml");
 headers.put("content-type", list);
 e.sendResponseHeaders(200, 0);
```

Unfortunately feed is displaying like xml (browser doesn't, ask me what to do with feed) and sniffing with livehttpheaders shows that there isn't content-type attribute.

Comment: (I can't remember the code off hand, but it looks like you are adding to the request instead of response headers.)

Comment: Tom's comment should be an answer. Adding content-type to headers object obtained using getRequestHeaders() is not going to affect what headers are sent in response.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can set the response headers like this:

```
Headers headers = exchange.getResponseHeaders();
headers.add("Content-Type", "application/atom+xml");
exchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, 0);
```